# How can i minimize the code in a class toggler that targets nav?

Tags: javascript, getelementsbytagname

I love clean code but I'm zero in javascript. I'd love to do two things to the super easy code below:

```js
function nav_open() {
  var myNav = document.getElementById('nav_anim');
  if (myNav.className == 'nav_closed') {
    myNav.className = 'nav_open';
  } else {
    myNav.className = 'nav_closed';
  }
}
```

1. Use `getElementsByTagName` to target the nav instead of giving it a useless id (in order to use only `<nav>` instead of `<nav id="nav_anim">` in the body. I tried some combos but none of them works.
2. Get rid of that ugly myNav name, is it mandatory? I know I can change it, but can I remove it? Is it possible to use something like
   `nav.className=='nav_closed'` or even better `className=='nav_closed'` instead of `myNav.className=='nav_closed'`

Comment: If you are 1000% (not a typo) sure that there always will be exact amount of `<nav>` elements, you can use `document.getElementsByTagName("nav")[n]` where `n` is (zero based) index of your `<nav>` in document.

Comment: Yes I am, It's a really easy website and I'm the only webmaster. Plain html and CSS 100% written by me in Notepad++. Thanks, It didnt' work because I missed the [n]

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest keeping the id on your nav, targetting your DOM elements using ids or classes is something that is commonly done and can speed up lookup. Using `getElementsByTagName()` adds unnecessary complexity and would need to traverse your entire DOM to find your element, so it isn't very efficient, espeicially if you just have one `nav` element. If you really want to, you could use querySelector to select the first `nav` item:

```js
const myNav = document.querySelector("nav");
```

At the end of the day though, if you want to interact with elements in your JavaScript code, you'll need to explicitly grab them (not counting [named access on the global window object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables) as it is [recommended not to use this](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/window-object.html#named-access-on-the-window-object)).

---

To further improve your toggle code, you could perform two toggles using [`DOMTokenList.toggle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle), one to hide your first class and one to add your other. Every time you run both toggles, they will add/remove both classes depending on whether they exist or not:

```js
const myNav = document.getElementById("nav_anim");
myNav.classList.toggle('nav_closed');
myNav.classList.toggle('nav_open');
```

See example below:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  btn.classList.toggle("on");
  btn.classList.toggle("off");
});
```

```css
.on {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.off {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" class="on">Click me</button>
```

Depending on your code, you may even be able to remove the `nav_closed` class by targeting your nav element that does not have the `nav_open` class:

```css
#nav_anim:not(.nav_open) {
  /* nav_closed styles */
}
```

With this setup, you can use just one toggle:

```js
const myNav = document.getElementById("nav_anim");
myNav.classList.toggle('nav_open');
```

See example below:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  btn.classList.toggle("on");
});
```

```css
.on {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

#btn:not(.on) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" class="on">Click me</button>
```

Comment: OMG thanks. I defintely need some time to study your answer but I think I'll go with the best one (the one that removes the other class).

Comment: @MarcoM. no worries, hope it answered your question

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with a [conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), like so:

```
var nav = document.getElementsByTagName("nav")[0];

(nav.classList.contains('nav_open')) ? nav.classList.remove('nav_open') : nav.classList.add('nav_open'));
```

This is like a 1 line if statement with 3 parameters:

**condition ? exprIfTrue : exprIfFalse**

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely better than the one I used. If I can't figure out the answer above, I'll go with this. Thanks man